# Tracking number in Email template magento 2 not working

Tags: email, sales-order, email-templates, magento2.3.5-p1, shipment-tracking

I have use in the Email templates ***"New Shippment"*** the variable tracking numer detail
The variable in BO magento 2 Email templates :

```
{{block class='Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

When i recieve the email i get no informations of tracking informations

**I use magento version 2.3.5-p1 , i wanna just get the informations of tracking number in email shippment.**

The variable of Order Summary is also empty

Answer (score 1):

**Use that line tracking number will be show
I hope it will be helpful**

```
   {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
```

**Like that**

```
<tr class="email-information">
    <td>
        {{depend comment}}
        <table class="message-info">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{var comment|escape|nl2br}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{/depend}}
        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
        <table class="order-details">
            <tr>
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6 style="color:#000;text-transform: uppercase;">{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h6>
                    <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                </td>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6 style="color:#000;text-transform: uppercase;">{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h6>
                    <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6 style="color:#000;text-transform: uppercase;">{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h6>
                    {{var payment_html|raw}}
                </td>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6 style="color:#000;text-transform: uppercase;">{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h6>
                    <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The block `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` is pretty generic, and I pretty sure that it will not deal with any tracking information.

I would recommend you change your class block for: `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Shipment\Items`

I am afraid  that the `{{block ...}}` directive will not work for you. Instead of that, you can use the directive `{{handle ... }}` like below:

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}`

You can find the same directive on Magento's shipment emails:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html#L64

I hope it helps you, good luck.